# How to set up boost bcp in linux? Unable to set the boost path and get runtime error

Tags: c++, linux, boost

I installed boost_1_55_0 and trying to use bcp to get a copy of the dependent header files, to package with the application.

So I have a UI folder with two .cpp files. The boost header I am using are boost/program_options.hpp and boost/filesystem.hpp.

I have an include folder with a copy of ALL the boost headers. So, I'd like to have a subset of the headers.

I have a lib folder with the dynamic libraries  libboost_program...options.so.1.55.0 and libboost_filesystem.so.1.55.0

Im trying to use bcp to get the subset of dependent headers for my application. I have installed it and created the binary. I am having trouble setting up the boost path.

I run bcp --scan /home/abc123/blabla/abc/UI/xyz.cpp and get

**** exception(205): std::runtime_error: The Boost path appears to have been incorrectly set: could not find boost/version.hpp in 
******** errors detected; see standard output for details ********

I have tried setting the path to the directory ~/boost_1_55_0 but it still gives me the same error. I also tried to include the path to the /usr/include/boost and tried a few options. Could not get it to work.

Comment: I tried by adding the following command line option:

--boost=/path/to/boost_directory

What would my path to boost directory be? I extracted boost_1_55_0 to the home folder and using it there.

Comment: I have this same problem with boost_1_59_0.  It occurs on both windows and linux.  This guy (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/boost-list/qqazl6YbrZs) encountered the same problem due to a mismatch between the way he installed bcp and the rest of boost, but I've messed around only in 1_59_0 so I don't think that's my problem.

Comment: In case anybody else has my problem: I managed to get it to work [under windows](http://www.technical-recipes.com/2014/using-subset-boost-in-windows/) by using forward slashes instead of backslashes `bcp --boost="C:/.../boost_1_59_0/"`  Still no luck under linux.